# Python € in filename

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I need to be able to read or rename a file that contains the character: €.
This character has a random position that I get with a. How can I do it?

```
import os
os.rename("C:\\Python2\\"+u"€.txt","test.txt")
```

Send me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    os.rename("C:\\Python2\\"+u"Ôé¼.txt","test.txt")
```

Comment: I'm not a python guy, but should your variable `u` have plus signs on both sides?  

`"C:\\Python2\\" + u + "€.txt"`

Comment: @KieranE the `u` is valid syntax for python 2.x - this creates a `unicode` string

Comment: @KieranE, no, it shouldn't as `u` isn't a variable, but a specifier that constructs a Unicode string.

Comment: You should probably drop that and use Python 3.x instead as it has _much_ better Unicode support.

Comment: do you now the name of the file or it is always random?

Comment: I couldn't replicate it with Python 2.7 on Linux.  Maybe it is an OS issue?  Do you have the same problem with Python 3?

Comment: it's a windows related issue, this piece of code worked perfectly on linux but didn't on both windows 7 and 10.

Comment: The symbol position its aleatory in filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) method:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
os.rename("C:/Python2/€.txt".decode('UTF-8'),"test.txt")
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @ArturodelPino Sorry, try it now. Tested on Windows 10 with Python 2.7

Comment: Tested in Windows 7 (Spanish)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.rename("C:/Python27/Ôé¼.txt".decode('UTF-8'),"test.txt")
WindowsError: [Error 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada

Comment: I'm sorry Works great!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "€" with "\u20ac".

This is the unicode for the euro sign.

```
mytext = "C:\\Python2\\\u20ac.txt"
print(mytext)
```

The result:

```
C:\Python2\€.txt
```

**EDIT FOR Python 2:**

```
eurosign = u"\u20AC"
mytext = "C:\\Python2\\" + eurosign + ".txt"
print(mytext)
```

The result:

```
C:\Python2\€.txt
```

Comment: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 11: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @ArturodelPino Can you please run this command in your console and try again? `chcp 65001`

Comment: @ArturodelPino if that doesn't work try this command before running the script: `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`